How to remove inactive RAID - zero-superblock failed?
What is my next step to remove inactive software RAID /dev/mdx ?
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc24
mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/sdc24 for write - not zeroing
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc25
mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/sdc25 for write - not zeroing
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$
